# Types of sleep modes for processes

Tags: process, sleep

I came across this while troubleshooting why our server is doing down everytime the oracle process is killed. I listed the oracle process running on the server using `ps aux | grep oracle` and here is the output:

```
oracle   21739  0.0  0.0 165068 17488 ?        Ssl  Oct14   0:18 /apps/11203/grid/bin/mdnsd.bin
oracle   21759  0.1  0.0 176556 25672 ?        Ssl  Oct14   1:14 /apps/11203/grid/bin/gpnpd.bin
oracle   21772  0.9  0.0 249528 31320 ?        Sl   Oct14   8:04 /apps/11203/grid/bin/gipcd.bin
oracle   21830  1.1  0.0 265760 115908 ?       SLl  Oct14   9:54 /apps/11203/grid/bin/ocssd.bin
oracle   21969  0.2  0.0 268648 29148 ?        Ssl  Oct14   2:10 /apps/11203/grid/bin/evmd.bin
oracle   22246  0.0  0.0  92420 13024 ?        S    Oct14    0:00 /apps/11203/grid/bin/evmlogger.bin -o /apps/11203/grid/evm/log/evmlogger.info -l /apps/11203/grid/evm/log/evmlogger.log
```

Right, all these processes are sleeping and from their status code there are under various types of sleeps - `Ssl, Sl, SLl`. I googled about the different kind of process sleeps and couldn't find only about Disk Sleep, Interruptible and non-Interruptible sleeps. I don't see any info about what looks like sub-statuses (the `Ssl, Sl, SLl` )of various sleeps. Anyone here knows how is SsL, Sl and SLl different?

From the comment from user 'chaos' I identified these statuses as:

```
Ssl - sleeping, is a session loader and multi-threaded. 
SL - sleeping, has pages locked into memory
Sl - sleeping, and the process is multi-threaded
```

So what does these mean? Does a process in 'SL - sleeping, has pages locked into memory', using the memory? If there are lots of those 'SL' processes, are they taking away memory from other processes?

(All these processes have their parent process as `init`, if that makes any difference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from the `ps` manpage:

> PROCESS STATE CODES:
>          Here are the different values that the s, stat and state output specifiers (header "STAT" or "S") will display to describe the
>          state of a process:
>
> ```
>    D    uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
>    R    running or runnable (on run queue)
>    S    interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
>    T    stopped, either by a job control signal or because it is being traced.
>    W    paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
>    X    dead (should never be seen)
>    Z    defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent.
>
>    For BSD formats and when the stat keyword is used, additional characters may be
>    displayed:
>    <    high-priority (not nice to other users)
>    N    low-priority (nice to other users)
>    L    has pages locked into memory (for real-time and custom IO)
>    s    is a session leader
>    l    is multi-threaded (using CLONE_THREAD, like NPTL pthreads do)
>    +    is in the foreground process group.
> ```

Comment: Thank you. I had seen this, but had ignored the last section about additional characters. So from the man output could these statuses mean:
Ssl - sleeping, is a session loader and multi-threaded.
SL - sleeping, has pages locked into memory
Sl - sleeping, and the process is multi-threaded